# Exitnodes: safe?

Tags: exit-relays

I've configured the torrc file to use a specific exitnode with strictexitnode 1.

I want to know if this compromised my privacy in any way. If I understand it correctly, Tor would still have two different entry and middle nodes, regardless of the exit node setting in the torrc file, which would mean that 99.99999% of the time the entry, middle node and exit node would not be the same and there would be no way to know my real IP address, even to the exit node owner?

Also, I have sent personal information with HTTPS services, using that node, but since it was HTTPS, if I understand correctly, the exit nodes owners would not be able to see it?

And my last question, the receiver of the personal information could see I have used a tor exit node, is that completely legal? if I wasnt doing anything wrong but just using Tor for anonmity?

Thanks to everyone who answers my questions

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this will compromise your privacy and anonymity.

It would be trivial for anyone observing traffic to discover that you're configured to use a single exit node. You're likely to be the only person using that Exit exclusively, which allows them to link all your activity on Tor together, both your activity you intend to be disassocated with your real identity and activity you perform that is linked to your identity could be linked together.

Infact your guard may be able figure out which exit you were using, by seeing that you never build circuits through it to a middle relay that is in the same family or /16 as your chosen exit.

Using `ExitNodes` is something you shouldn't do. It will always harm your anonymity.

No, the exit will not be able to see into HTTPS (or any other TLS) connections.

I'm not a lawyer and I don't think anyone can answer questions about legality, it depends on lots of things specific to you and your situation like your local laws and the service providers ToS. Ask a lawyer.

Comment: Infact your guard may be able figure out which exit you were using, by seeing that you never build circuits through it to a middle relay that is in the same family or /16 as your chosen exit. What does that mean? Can the entry, middle or exit node know my real IP address?

Comment: The entry knows your real IP, and it can see where the next relay is. It doesn't know the Exit but over time a pattern will build up that shows what middle nodes you never pick (which other clients would) due to the fact that you only use a single exit.

Comment: Even though I've only picked an exitnode in the torrc file (and no entry or middle exit nodes were picked, I guess they are picked automatically?) somehow the entry node could figure out what the exit node is and know every website I have visited and every conversation that didn't use HTTPS (or any other TLS connection)? Would the entry node be the same every time? What's the likelihood of the entry node who knows my real IP, to know the exit node and every website I have visited? Thanks for explaining how it works

Comment: The entry is the same for long periods of time (months), it's called your [Guard](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/research-problem-better-guard-rotation-parameters). You connect directly to it, so it knows your IP address. It can't see the traffic associated with the exit, since that is encrypted between you and the exit but it does reveal something about your Tor configuration.